# netbeans and svn problem

Tags: svn, netbeans, editor

I'm having problems with netbeans and subversion. It has worked perfectly in the past, but recently it stopped committing the files. I keep getting this error message:

Cannot determine repositoryRootUrl for selected context:
{path}

When i select Show changes from the project view it gives me this message:

Commit failed (details follow):

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Entry has no URL
'/Users/stephen/mnt/dev-web1.**************.****/***************************/branch' has no ancestry information

What could be the cause of this issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at this [netbeans post](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-78849.html) which tackles a problem similar to yours.

> Select the project in the Projects view and call Subversion -> Show
>   changes from the context menu.

Comment: Sadly enough that did not fix the problem. it now says:


org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Entry has no URL
Commit failed (details follow):
'/Users/stephen/mnt/dev-web1.breezz.nl/xml.dev.breezz.nl/branch' has no ancestry information